# 4 Questions for mining bitcoin in cloud

Tags: mining-setup, cloud-mining

I have four questions about the general mining bitcoin  in the cloud.

1. I have a unlimited bandwith web hosting . Can i mining bitcoin with web host ? (my web host support : CGI, PHP, ASP.NET, SSI, FrontPage Extensions, Perl, Python, Ruby)
2. Can i mining bitcoin in heroku or google app engine or amazon aws ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it may be possible, it would most certainly cost you your account with any knowledgeable web host. Even if you could get a miner to run, it will peg the CPU and make the rest of the machine unusable, impacting performance for other users on shared hosting and not really be beneficial on dedicated or VPS hosting.

**Please don't do this. It's not the way to do it and the return will not be worth it for anyone involved.**